# NA induced by coercion _ mean and SD _ percentages

Tags: r, dplyr, coercion

I am trying to get some means and SD for the 3 groups that I have under the column 'Group' (0, 1 2) in the columns 'Variable1' and 'Variable2'.

**DATASET** Sorry that I need to provide it like this, but I don't know how to paste it otherwise

```
> dput(test)

structure(list(Subject_ID = structure(1:163, .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", 
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", 
"137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", 
"146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", 
"155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163"
), class = "factor"), Variable1 = c(270, 206, 291, 81, 254, 253, 
224, 324, 139, 164, 113, 140, 158, 202, 324, 99, 201, 222, 244, 
197, 91, 200, 366, 203, 151, 202, 237, 194, 72, 227, 134, 270, 
281, 260, 276, 110, 76, 364, 296, 222, 300, 203, 100, 295, 219, 
235, 277, 202, 132, 243, 222, 317, 153, 232, 266, 254, 224, 267, 
83, 302, 230, 217, 474, 235, NA, 244, 287, 261, 261, 222, 218, 
328, 302, 282, 105, 213, 254, 323, 259, 297, 94, 429, 297, 253, 
207, 234, 171, 225, 310, 216, 172, 392, 240, 306, 167, 40, 230, 
405, 278, 140, 385, 207, 96, 301, 130, 137, 260, 178, 229, 174, 
157, 116, 44, 244, 237, 220, 240, 223, 317, 232, 132, 168, 289, 
55, 267, 317, 251, 196, 160, 149, 308, 281, 287, 193, 161, 279, 
270, 273, 397, 138, 272, 208, 231, 291, 245, 351, 238, 100, 352, 
66, 224, 273, 262, 259, 217, 334, 264, 293, 412, 157, 164, 263, 
199), Variable2 = c(NA, 6.1, 4.3, 18.6, 6.4, 6.7, 6.9, 9.2, 4.2, 
6.9, 14.3, 21.6, 2.9, 11.9, 6.1, 12.7, 6, 5.2, 4.5, 6.1, 9.6, 
3.5, 6.6, 5.4, 3.9, 3.1, 4.3, 5.1, 69.1, 4.1, 22.3, 6.3, 8, 10.2, 
6.4, 11.2, 13.8, 6.5, 6.2, 4.8, 6.5, 5.5, 29.9, 10.9, 10.7, 4.7, 
5.3, 25.4, 11.8, 10, 9, 8, 6.8, 6.6, 6, 7.7, 6.5, 6.4, 18.2, 
11.9, 11.8, 3.9, 18.8, 7.6, 5.1, 7.7, 5.3, 5.7, 5.3, 6.3, 2.7, 
4.5, 6.3, 7.5, 11.9, 6.8, 3.2, 12, 7.8, 4, 48, 3.9, 7.9, 15.4, 
6.8, 4.5, 3.7, 6.9, 3.8, 10.1, 3.7, 5.1, 6, 5.3, 7.2, 8.6, 7.6, 
7.1, 5.9, 5.1, 8.9, 17.3, 27.7, 6.2, 5.8, 26.3, 7.9, 13.5, 9.7, 
11.7, 6.8, 18.4, 27.7, 26.3, 12, 46.5, 4.7, 11.4, 5.4, 3.1, 23.4, 
12, 16.6, 27.7, 3.7, 6.1, 6.8, 8.1, 20.4, 14.3, 6, 6.9, 8.4, 
8.8, 16.9, 6.1, 7.3, 3.5, 10.8, 16, 5.7, 9.5, 10.7, 8.5, 7.7, 
6.9, 8.7, 22.4, 8.2, 16.7, 7.6, 6.1, 7.1, 11.9, 5.3, 5.4, 8.3, 
6.8, 12.2, 11.5, 6.9, 5.9, 4.5), Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-163L), class = "data.frame")
```

**CODE**

I have transformed the variables 1 and 2 in numeric:

```
data$Variable1 <- as.numeric(as.character(data$Variable1))
data$Variable2 <- as.numeric(as.character(data$Variable2))
```

and asked for means and SDs as:

```
meanSD<-ddply(data, .(Group),summarise,
          meanV1= mean(Variable1),na.rm = TRUE,
          SD_V1=sd(Variable1),na.rm = TRUE,
          meanV2= mean(Variable2),na.rm = TRUE,
          SD_V2=sd(Variable2),na.rm = TRUE)
```

**OUTPUT**

The table that I get:

1. For Variable1:

[image]

2. For Variable2:

   `Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
     Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.`
     `Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.`
   `In addition: Warning message:`
   `In mean.default(Variable2) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

In previous analysis I was having an error saying: `NAs induced by coercion.`

**PROBLEM** 
Well, the problem is obvious: Why do I get NAs when my data has numbers on it?

I was able to do the calculations in Excel without a problem. But I am worried that my data actually contains problems. And I need help with this.

Million thanks in advance for your help!

Lili

Answer (score 2):

Move the `na.rm=T` inside the parentheses:

```
library(plyr)
meanSD<-ddply(data, .(Group),summarise,
              meanV1= mean(Variable1,na.rm = TRUE),
              SD_V1=sd(Variable1,na.rm = TRUE),
              meanV2= mean(Variable2,na.rm = TRUE),
              SD_V2=sd(Variable2,na.rm = TRUE))

> meanSD
  Group   meanV1    SD_V1    meanV2     SD_V2
1     0 207.6964 80.41798  8.650909  5.415816
2     1 224.4815 72.39221 11.327273 10.108128
3     2 255.8077 83.28431 10.161538  9.297399
```

And the `dplyr` alternative (note that `plyr` is officially retired):

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise_if(
    is.numeric,
    list(mean = mean, sd = sd),
    na.rm = TRUE
  )
```

Comment: Good point. I changed it to `dplyr` and added the note that plyr is officially 'retired' Hopefully that works.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried the code and it works for some means and SDs but not for others. 
Giving me this error: 

Error in (function (x, na.rm = FALSE, type = 7)  : 
  formal argument "na.rm" matched by multiple actual arguments

Comment: hard to say without seeing more, but try changing the summarise segment to this: `summarise_if(is.numeric, list(mean = mean,sd = sd), na.rm=T)` If that works, I'll update the answer.

Comment: so you mean:  meanSD<-ddply(df, .(Group),summarise_if(is.numeric, list(mean = mean,sd = sd), na.rm=T),
              meanV1= mean(Variable1),
              SD_V1=sd(Variable1),
              meanV2= mean(Variable2),
              SD_V2=sd(Variable2))

Comment: Not quite. ddply (as part of plyr) is permanently retired and replaced by dplyr. I've updated the response with the suggestion above. If the error you mentioned before persists, I'd need more info to try another diagnosis.

Comment: **Amazing! that works!! great. The only thing is. My dataset is HUGE. How can I modify the script to get just 2 variables from the whole dataset?
**I need to add IQR too but doesn't work if I add it to the list(mean = mean, sd = sd, IQR=IQR)

Answer (score 0):

As AHart said the problem was solved with:

```
library(plyr)
meanSD<-ddply(data, .(Group),summarise,
              meanV1= mean(Variable1,na.rm = TRUE),
              SD_V1=sd(Variable1,na.rm = TRUE),
              meanV2= mean(Variable2,na.rm = TRUE),
              SD_V2=sd(Variable2,na.rm = TRUE))
```

The following problems came from the following chunk. I had to # the Produce table to be able to make the whole code to work. Awkward. But this was the solution.

```
    new = New_DH[!duplicated(New_DH$names), ]
write.csv(new, file="new.csv")

# Produce table
#columns_to_display = colnames(new)[1:5]
#for_display = new[columns_to_display]
#kable_input = kable(head(for_display), "latex", booktabs=T)
#kable_styling(kable_input, latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down"))
```